# Intersection of two lists in numba

Tags: python, performance, numba

I would like to know the fastest way to compute the intersection of two list within a numba function. Just for clarification: an example of the intersection of two lists:

```
Input : 
lst1 = [15, 9, 10, 56, 23, 78, 5, 4, 9]
lst2 = [9, 4, 5, 36, 47, 26, 10, 45, 87]
Output :
[9, 10, 4, 5]
```

The problem is, that this needs to be computed within the numba function and therefore e.g. sets can not be used. Do you have an idea?
My current code is very basic. I assume that there is room for improvement.

```
@nb.njit
def intersection:
   result = []
   for element1 in lst1:
      for element2 in lst2:
         if element1 == element2:
            result.append(element1)
   ....
```

Comment: You should convert both lists to a set and then find the set intersection

Comment: sets cannot be used within a numba function.

Comment: `numba` supports sets, but only if they contain objects of a single type - which in your case they do? https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html

Comment: There are different algorithms: If your lists are short (n and m elements), then the naive O(n*m) algorithm could be the fastest. Otherwise converting a list to a set will result in O(m+n) running time. However, for sorted lists (without the need to sort them) the running time will also be O(n+m) but faster than the set version. So what is your scenario?

Comment: Thank you. You are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since numba compiles and runs your code in machine code, your probably at the best for such a simple operation.
I ran some benchmarks below

```
@nb.njit
def loop_intersection(lst1, lst2):
    result = []
    for element1 in lst1:
        for element2 in lst2:
            if element1 == element2:
                result.append(element1)
    return result

@nb.njit
def set_intersect(lst1, lst2):
    return set(lst1).intersection(set(lst2))
```

Resuls

```
loop_intersection
40.4 µs ± 1.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

set_intersect
42 µs ± 6.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: You are right. In my case the naive approach seems to be actually the fastest! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I played with this a bit to try and learn something, realizing that the answer has already been given. When I run the accepted answer I get a return value of [9, 10, 5, 4, 9]. I wasn’t clear if the repeated 9 was acceptable or not. 
Assuming it’s OK, I ran a trial using list comprehension to see it made any difference. My results:

```
from numba import jit

def createLists():
    l1 = [15, 9, 10, 56, 23, 78, 5, 4, 9]
    l2 = [9, 4, 5, 36, 47, 26, 10, 45, 87]

@jit
def listComp():
    l1, l2 = createLists()
    return [i for i in l1 for j in l2 if i == j]
```

%timeit listComp()
5.84 microseconds +/- 10.5 nanoseconds

Or if you can can use Numpy this code is even faster and removes the duplicate "9" and is much faster with the Numba signature.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, int64

@jit(int64[:](int64[:], int64[:]))
def JitListComp(l1, l2):
    l3 = np.array([i for i in l1 for j in l2 if i == j])
    return np.unique(l3) # and i not in crossSec]

@jit
def CreateList():
    l1 = np.array([15, 9, 10, 56, 23, 78, 5, 4, 9])
    l2 = np.array([9, 4, 5, 36, 47, 26, 10, 45, 87])
    return JitListComp(l1, l2)

CreateList()
Out[39]: array([ 4,  5,  9, 10])

%timeit CreateList()
1.71 µs ± 10.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use set operation for this:

```
def intersection(lst1, lst2): 
    return list(set(lst1) & set(lst2))
```

then simply call the function `intersection(lst1,lst2)`. This will be the easiest way.